# Overwrite reference type without breaking references

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to write a system for loading a bunch of variables from disk at runtime. For a Unity game.

I have a wrapper class that allows floats, ints etc to be passed as references:

```
public class RefProperty<T>
{
    private T val;
    public T Val
    {
        get => val;
        set => val = value;
    }
    
    public RefProperty()
    {
    }
    public RefProperty(T value)
    {
        Val = value;
    }
}
```

I want to overwrite `val` with one loaded from disk without breaking references. In the following, `target = source` will update the value of `target`, but `reference` will no longer update when `target` is modified.

```
public class Program
{
    private RefProperty<float> source = new RefProperty<float>();
    private RefProperty<float> target = new RefProperty<float>();
    private RefProperty<float> reference = new RefProperty<float>();

    public void Run()
    {
        target.Val = 1;
        reference = target;
        Debug.Log(reference.Val); // returns 1
        
        source.Val = 5;
        target = source;
        Debug.Log(reference.Val); // returns 1
        
        ///////////////////////////////
        
        target.Val = 1;
        reference = target;
        Debug.Log(reference.Val); // returns 1
        
        source.Val = 5;
        target.Val = source.Val;
        Debug.Log(reference.Val); // returns 5
    }
}
```

The 2nd approach `target.Val = source.Val` does work. However, I am trying to avoid that because ultimately I want to iterate through the fields of a class holding loads of these with different types, and some child classes, and replace all the values without having to know the types:

```
public class RefPropertyChild : RefProperty<float>
{
    // float specific features
    public RefPropertyChild(float value)
    {
        Val = value;
    }
}


public class Parameters
{
    public RefProperty<bool> p1 = new RefProperty<bool>(true);
    public RefProperty<int> p2 = new RefProperty<int>(5);
    public RefPropertyChild p3 = new RefPropertyChild(6);
}


public class LoadData
{
    private Parameters sourceParams;
    private Parameters targetParams;

    void load()
    {
        foreach (FieldInfo field in typeof(Parameters).GetFields())
        {
            field.SetValue(targetParams, field.GetValue(sourceParams));
        }
    }
}
```

As before, this does modify the values, but breaks the references, I am assuming because it's pointing to a different memory location now? Is there any way to do this or do I have to explicitly handle each type and use the getter / setters?

Comment: Using properties seems to be the way anyway. I would suggest having an inner class in Parameters that can serialize/deserialize itself. A class optimized for serializing so to say and where its irrelevant that its reference changes. And the outer class Parameters then only forwards its properties to the inner classes properties. Some kind of a facade pattern.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to replace the references with an ID, and store the actual objects somewhere else. This will likely be easier to manage if you are using some kind of DTO to represent objects when serializing. Something like:

```
long maxId = 0;
var myReferences = new Dictionary<object, long>();
foreach(var obj in myObjects){
    var r = obj.MyReferenceProperty;
    var id = myReferences.TryGetValue(r, out var t) ? t: myReferences[r] = maxId++;
     
     Use id in place of your property in the DTO or serialization format.
}

// Serialize the myReferences dictionary
```

When deserializing you would be doing the reverse. Deserializing the list of references, and replacing the property with the corresponding reference object. You may need some way to include type information when doing the serialization of the dictionary, so that you are able to deserialize the properties to the correct type.

Some serialization libraries has built in support for this. Protobuf .Net had the AsReference attribute, but it looks [like that has been obsoleted](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/issues/597).

Another alternative is to also use some kind of id-based system at runtime. So objects would share a common reference-manager object. And any time you need to read or write the value of a common property you would hand the reference manager your id and get the value back. This makes the serialization easier, but will make the implementation more complex.